# view "add friend" only if that user is a friend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, scope

I want to view the `method: :post` only if the user is a friend. right now my view looks like so

```
<% if current_user.friends  %>

        <% else %>
        <%= link_to 'add friend' , friendships_path(:friend_id => user), method: :post, class: "add-friend" %>
        <% end %>
```

but when I do it this way nothing is rendered.

if I put it in-between the `<% if %>` and `<% else %>` statements then it shows the add-friend for all users.

my User model is:

```
has_many :active_friends, -> { where(friendships: { approved: true}) }, :through => :friendships, :source => :friend, dependent: :destroy
         has_many :passive_friends, -> { where(friendships: { approved: true}) }, :through => :passive_friendships, :source => :user, dependent: :destroy
         has_many :pending_friends, -> { where(friendships: { approved: false}) }, :through => :friendships, :source => :friend, dependent: :destroy
         has_many :requested_friendships, -> { where(friendships: { approved: false}) }, :through => :passive_friendships, :source => :user, dependent: :destroy

def friends
           active_friends | passive_friends 
         end
```

so to reiterate, how can I setup the view to only show the post method when not a friend?

Answer (score 0):

So, the `friends` method will return `[]` for someone with no active or passive friends, `[]` is `true` in ruby, so the `if` will always be true.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, so how can I rephrase it? I dont think you really answered the question.

Comment: I don't really understand your question actually, your conditional seems to be trying to do "when `current_user` has no friends` but then your question asks "when not a friend" - when who is not a friend of whom? If you're really asking how do you create a boolean to check if `current_user.friends` is an empty array, then I think you should probably spend some time and learn ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your condition: `<%= if current_user.friends.present? %>`